# What is the difference between Testflight itunesconnect version with testflightapp.com

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I've been using using Testflightapp.com to deliver beta version of my app for years and now I'm considering to use the itunesconnect version of testflight because of its advantage of 1000 external beta users.
Anybody know what is the difference of these two versions? Should I continue using the testflightapp.com version (because I'm already comfortable with the current system) or should I move using itunesconnect version immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TestFlight Beta Testing (iTunes Connect version)**

1. Uses AppStore provisioning profile which mean you don't need to manage UUIDs
2. Builds are distributed through an iOS [app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/testflight/id899247664?mt=8)
3. The install expires after 30 days
4. You're allowed to install up to 25 internal users (by adding their emails in itunesconnect)
5. You can install up to 1000 devices, but app needs to go through a review process (often takes 2 to 3 days)

We are currently using both TestFlights, the original TestFlight for internal testing which gives us 100 devices. We use the "new" TestFlight for external beta testing to take advantage of deploying to 1000 devices. We'll probably eventually move to the new TestFlight as I predict Apple killing the old service in the future.

Comment: how do you go about managing your test builds in TestFlight Beta? Any ideas? see what i mean on this SO question I just wrote up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459535/ios-app-version-and-build-numbers-for-itunesconnect-testflight  Thanks!