# iOS app version and build numbers for iTunesConnect TestFlight

Tags: ios, jenkins, app-store-connect, testflight

My question relates to the restrictions in **iTunes Connect** for Version and Build number. We are only allowed 3 non-negative integers and the Build number has to be incremental.

I am setting up a **Jenkins** job to automatically upload my builds to **iTunes Connect** so that testers can then download them.

**Problem:** How do we ensure an incremental build number? Even if we did manually change it in Xcode before every commit (which seems wrong) there are more than one dev working on the project so there is no way we can all sync our commits and incremental numbers across the team.

**Nice to have:** My team works in several branches. It would be helpful if I could specify the branch name or some other description in the Build field. In the stand alone Test Flight (to be deprecated end of Feb 2015), we could upload a build with some letters.

Would love some input here!

And if iTunes Connect Test Flight is not the answer to distribute test builds, what other services are people using?

Thanks!

Comment: I used the Apple test flight for an app recently and my impression was that the intent of Apple is for developers to only use it for final Beta testing. The things that led me to this impression are that the app still needs to go through a light weight review process before released to external testers and you can only do that twice a day.

Comment: I'm not sure. I was planning on using it for internal testers only for the moment. I am still suspicious whether my flow is the correct intended way though. I'm not so happy about the crowded iTunes Connect as we have many commits/builds per day...

Comment: In my experience with ITC, it takes about 1 hour from submission before the app is ready for internal testers. My app is kinda big, 350MB, so that may impact the processing speed also.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I managed to get my builds on iTunes Connect finally. yay. But the time it takes does prove to be problematic indeed. What do you end up using for your app? We do an average of 30 builds a day here.

Comment: I've used HockeyApp with great success before. It's much faster for turning around the builds.  I used to use testflightapp.com, but that's going away now that Apple bought it.

Comment: We might have to consider HockeyApp too. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Jenkins there is a $BUILD_NUMBER parameter that lasts the life of the job. You can append this to the end of the build number parameter in the info.plist. If the beginning of the build number in info.plist is 3.1. then your real build number becomes 3.1.$BUILD_NUMBER from Jenkins. There's a program called plist_buddy (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html) which you can use to edit the info.plist file.

It really doesn't matter if there are gaps in the sequence as long as it's incrementing. The 3.1. part would be manually managed so that the lead developer increments that at the beginning of a release. This approach assumes that you've got 1 job to do the build. If you have multiple jobs doing builds of the same app you could possibly use something like the date/time in Unix format, it's a large number and usually doesn't go backwards.

Comment: Thanks! that's a great idea and should do the trick. I'm stuck with a 'Missing code-signing certificate' issue atm that prevents me from uploading to iTunes so I can't verify yet.

Comment: Take a look at this Jenkins plugin. It has saved me many hours of fiddling with keychains and signing identities:  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Keychains+and+Provisioning+Profiles+Plugin